# Time is lost on boot

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate and my time is unconfiguring when I turn on my note. I dual boot and only this OS is this happening, my time zone is correct and in some cases, it sets the time automatically after a notebook on-time. Does anyone know how I solve?

Comment: You mean that one OS is displaying the current local time and the other OS is displaying UTC time?

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes.

Comment: @Douglas In that case the linked duplicate post is *exactly* what you're looking for. I had the same time with Ubuntu 16.04/Arch Linux and Windows 7. In my case, I decided to set Windows to see the BIOS clock as UTC, but it's also possible to tell Ubuntu to read it as local time. You may decide.